# how to understand the assignment expression "a=(b=4)=3"

Tags: c++

everyone. my question is, in c++, why the assignment expression "a=(b=4)=3" is correct? I know that the return value of b = 4 is 4, but why can it be assigned 3 again? Is it still a variable? thank you.

Comment: `b = 4` returns a reference to `b`. `a=(b=4)=3` is similar to `b = 4; b = 3; a = 3;`. You can see it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ZEQ28f)

Comment: This is one of the many differences between C and C++. In C this is invalid, because assignment returns the assigned value instead of a reference to the variable.

Answer (score 2):

`b = 4` returns a reference to `b`. `a=(b=4)=3` is similar to `b = 4; b = 3; a = 3;`. The assembly for `a=(b=4)=3` is

```
mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], 4
mov     dword ptr [rbp - 8], 3
mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 3
```

You can see it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ZEQ28f)

Answer (score 0):

b = 4 returns a reference to b which reduces the statement to a = b = 3. Then the righthand side of the equals sign gets assigned to the left as normal.

It's the same as

```
b = 4;
b = 3;
a = b;
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/ if you want more details on it

Answer (score 0):

You can look at a table with the operator precedence.

- First we have `(` and `)`, so a=(b=4)=3 becomes a=b=3 with b being assigned to 4.
- Than we look at the direction of the direction of the `=` which is from right to left, so 3 is first assigned to `b` and than is `b` assigned to `a`, which makes `a` 3 as well.

With this link you can look for the operator precedence and the direction (left to right or right to left).

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence